# Autowire Class with Interface as param in Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony

Given a class `Publisher` like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Util\Publisher;


use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class Publisher
{

    protected $topic = null;
    protected $bus;

    /**
     * Publisher constructor.
     * @param MessageBusInterface $bus
     */
    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $this->topic = getenv('TOPIC_MAIN_URL');
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    ...

}
```

I would like to autowire it in my controllers like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/_exp/_exp", name="exp")
 */
public function expAction(Publisher $publisher)
{
    ...
}
```

and I added this to my `services.yaml`:

```
Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface: ~

App\Util\Publisher\Publisher:
    autowire: true
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface']
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface

Is that related to the MessageBusInterface or am I doing something wrong with the autowiring. I followed [The Symfony docs for autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#an-autowiring-example) and they seem to be the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `MessageBusInterface` service is already declared by Symfony Messenger component.
Try to remove `Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface: ~` from your `services.yaml`, otherwise you are overriding the default definition.

A note for clarification: `MessageBusInterface` service does not really exists, it in an alias over the "default bus" service. You can declare other buses, cf [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger/multiple_buses.html)